How to obtain Lettuce Redis Client from Spring Boot?
I need to obtain a lettuce Redis client to perform xautoclaim.
xautoclaim is not exposed in Spring Data Redis.
I thought about obtaining client variable from LettuceConnectionFactory using reflection but maybe there is a better way...

Did you check out this discussion - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-redis/issues/2316?

Yes, I even wrote a comment there :)

Apologies, did not map the name to the nickname :) Long story short I think the solution you provided there is more or less the best way to do it right now

@TihomirMateev, honestly, I don't like this solution—it leaks connections to Redis. I plan to submit a PR with XAUTOCLAIM support, but it probably won't be merged soon.

Oh, absolutely, if anything this solution is a temporary patch until the proper support is provided in the spring-data-redis. Totally agree with you on that.
